# Pivot_Longer is creating more rows than expected

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I am using a dataset which records how governments are responsding to Coronavirus with policies.
For plotting purposes, i am using pivot_longer to contain all of the policies in one column and their corresponding values in another.

To check if this has worked correctly, i have filtered for one specific country, the UK, and for one specific policy, school closings. There should be 253 values (as of 9th september 2020) and yet there are 5 times that amount for some reason. I believe the first 253 values are correct but i don't know how i have created the extra values. I have tried a combination of things to fix this but i have not had any luck. If anyone could explain to me what i have done wrong and how to fix it, i would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

response <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/master/data/OxCGRT_latest.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")


## setting correct date format with lubridate 
response$Date <- ymd(response$Date)

##Removing some variables from the dataset 
response <- response %>%
  select(-contains(c("Notes", "IsGeneral", "StringencyIndex", "Flag", "Stringency", "HealthIndex", "SupportIndex",
                     "ResponseIndex", "RegionName", "RegionCode", "CountryCode")))

## a small preview of the dataset
head(response[, c(1:4)])
#>   CountryName       Date C1_School.closing C2_Workplace.closing
#> 1       Aruba 2020-01-01                 0                    0
#> 2       Aruba 2020-01-02                 0                    0
#> 3       Aruba 2020-01-03                 0                    0
#> 4       Aruba 2020-01-04                 0                    0
#> 5       Aruba 2020-01-05                 0                    0
#> 6       Aruba 2020-01-06                 0                    0


pivot <- response %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = C1_School.closing:M1_Wildcard,
    names_to = "policy",
    values_to = "value"
  )

## each country should have 253 rows for each policy 

pivot %>%
  filter(CountryName == "United Kingdom",
         policy == "C1_School.closing")
#> # A tibble: 1,265 x 6
#>    CountryName    Date       ConfirmedCases ConfirmedDeaths policy         value
#>    <chr>          <date>              <int>           <int> <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 United Kingdom 2020-01-01              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  2 United Kingdom 2020-01-02              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  3 United Kingdom 2020-01-03              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  4 United Kingdom 2020-01-04              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  5 United Kingdom 2020-01-05              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  6 United Kingdom 2020-01-06              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  7 United Kingdom 2020-01-07              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  8 United Kingdom 2020-01-08              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#>  9 United Kingdom 2020-01-09              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#> 10 United Kingdom 2020-01-10              0               0 C1_School.clo~     0
#> # ... with 1,255 more rows

## there are 5x as many rows as needed. 
## there should only be 253 days of data for one policy and one country
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Rows are created for each variable.

Comment: There is a row for each value of the policy. When you run `X = pivot %>% filter(CountryName == "United Kingdom", policy == "C1_School.closing")` and `length(unique(X$value))` you obtain the value 5..

Comment: @Taufi, I thought this might be the cause. Is there a way to avoid this? I thought it would just use the corresponding values. Or is the only work around to just somehow slice the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving deep in your data I found that there are duplicated dates. That is a main issue and you as data analyst must know what to do with that. I include a code solution that allows identifying the duplicated dates with an id variable so that you can filter which dates are correct. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#Load data
response <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/master/data/OxCGRT_latest.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

## setting correct date format with lubridate 
response$Date <- ymd(response$Date)

##Removing some variables from the dataset 
response <- response %>%
  select(-contains(c("Notes", "IsGeneral", "StringencyIndex", "Flag", "Stringency", "HealthIndex", "SupportIndex",
                     "ResponseIndex", "RegionName", "RegionCode", "CountryCode")))
```

Next, we will identify the duplicated rows by each country and date and save into `response2`:

```
#Mutate
response %>% 
  arrange(CountryName,Date) %>%
  group_by(CountryName,Date ) %>%
  mutate(id=1:n()) -> response2
```

Now, we will reshape data:

```
#Reshape
pivot <- response2 %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(CountryName,Date,id),
    names_to = "policy",
    values_to = "value"
  )
```

Then you have to decide which date to choose. Here I will choose the first date (`id==1`):

```
#Code
example <- pivot %>%
  filter(CountryName == "United Kingdom",
         policy == "C1_School.closing",id==1)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 253 x 5
# Groups:   CountryName, Date [253]
   CountryName    Date          id policy            value
   <fct>          <date>     <int> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 United Kingdom 2020-01-01     1 C1_School.closing     0
 2 United Kingdom 2020-01-02     1 C1_School.closing     0
 3 United Kingdom 2020-01-03     1 C1_School.closing     0
 4 United Kingdom 2020-01-04     1 C1_School.closing     0
 5 United Kingdom 2020-01-05     1 C1_School.closing     0
 6 United Kingdom 2020-01-06     1 C1_School.closing     0
 7 United Kingdom 2020-01-07     1 C1_School.closing     0
 8 United Kingdom 2020-01-08     1 C1_School.closing     0
 9 United Kingdom 2020-01-09     1 C1_School.closing     0
10 United Kingdom 2020-01-10     1 C1_School.closing     0
# ... with 243 more rows
```

Which has the expected number of rows you want.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Duck's answer there are duplicate dates in your data. These are due to multiple rows per country for some countries reflecting different regions of the same country. Using the suggested method for the data description in the [github repo](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker) you can clean the data such that you only remain with aggregated country levels.

To do so adapt your code to leave in the `RegionCode` column and filter for only entries with empty region code:

```
response <- response %>%
  select(-contains(c("Notes", "IsGeneral", "StringencyIndex", "Flag", "Stringency", "HealthIndex", "SupportIndex",
                     "ResponseIndex", "RegionName", "CountryCode"))) %>% 
  filter(RegionCode == "")
```

Now pivoting will produce your expected result:

```
pivot <- response %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = C1_School.closing:M1_Wildcard,
    names_to = "policy",
    values_to = "value"
  )
pivot %>%
  filter(CountryName == "United Kingdom",
         policy == "C1_School.closing")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 253 x 7
   CountryName    RegionCode Date       ConfirmedCases ConfirmedDeaths policy            value
   <chr>          <chr>      <date>              <int>           <int> <chr>             <dbl>
 1 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-01              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 2 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-02              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 3 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-03              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 4 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-04              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 5 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-05              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 6 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-06              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 7 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-07              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 8 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-08              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
 9 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-09              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
10 United Kingdom ""         2020-01-10              0               0 C1_School.closing     0
# ... with 243 more rows
```

Comment: I also spotted that shortly after reading Duck's post but i was too embarrassed to point it out hahaha. Thank you for posting though!